# Django Measurement Objects - locale info

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n

Django has some nice [measurement helpers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/measure/), but I can't figure out how they tie in with its [i18n and l10n infrastructure](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/). Is there any way to know what are the user's preferred units (e.g. miles vs kilometers)? The countries that use miles are more or less well known, so I can just hard code them, but that seems terribly non-Pythonic. What's the recommended way? Also, is there an idiom for storing distances in the database and then displaying them in the user's relevant locale?